# Need help identifying Japanese font

Tags: fonts, font-identification, japanese

It's from a tamagotchi product. I've been searching absolutely everywhere, from free to paid sites, just to know the name of this font. If anyone has a clue, I would really appreciate the help!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you search for えれがんと 書体, you should find multiple typefaces in this style. In general, highly stylized fonts like this are only available for kana and (sometimes) Roman alphabets, with a different typeface used for the kanji characters (of which there are many thousands).

It looks to me like the font you're after is called [えれがんとMat-UB](http://www.akibatec.net/wabunfont/library/fontworks/kana2.html). In the example below, it's been paired with another font called [マティス-UB](http://www.akibatec.net/wabunfont/library/fontworks/classic.html).

[You can try out the font here.](https://fontworks.co.jp/fontsearch/matisseelegantopro-ub/?word=%E3%81%82%E3%81%BE%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%84%E3%82%B9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%BC%E3%83%84%E3%81%A8%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E3%81%8C%E5%BA%83%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9F%E3%81%B0%E3%82%81%E3%82%81%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1)

[image: えれがんとMat-UB + マティス-UB font sample]

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helps. My sister also found this and I think it's the same one you found. :) https://cute-freefont.flop.jp/typelabo_eregant.html